# How to implement a multipart post request in c# wp8.1 (winrt)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Already second day trying to implement a multipart post request, but so far I have failed.

Task: to send 1 or 2 pictures to the server.

Please tell me how to do this in Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT). Already tried a huge number of links on the Internet, but nothing happened.

p.s. in the description of the API server written that you must submit a request in the following format.

```
   {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "files": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "file"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Yes, of course. Here is my code. I searched the Internet and eventually tried to implement this. Interestingly, it worked and sent the data to the server. only the North returned the error: "data error", so I sent out in the wrong format. I assume it's because not json created structure, about which I wrote above.

```
public async static Task<bool> UploadFiles(StorageFile file)
{
    var streamData = await file.OpenReadAsync();
    var bytes = new byte[streamData.Size];
    using (var dataReader = new DataReader(streamData))
    {
        await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)streamData.Size);
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
    }
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent form = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent();
    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.StringContent(UserLogin), "username");
    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.StringContent(UserPassword), "password");
    form.Add(new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(bytes, 0, bytes.Length), "files", "items");
    form.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(UploadFilesURI, form);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    httpClient.Dispose();
    string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   return true;
}
```

Sorry for this style of code. Haven't quite figured out how to insert it correctly in the posts

Comment: *Already tried a huge number of links on the Internet, but nothing happened.* What does nothing happened mean? Could you please post you actual code, otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: Yes, of course. I have attached the code below. Sorry

Comment: So the problem is that your JSON is malformed? You can't get the right structure for it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, judging by the API you want to send the files to the server and in the description of the API is the query structure. Therefore, I concluded that I must insert the multipart and json. Could be.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the query (top) and response (bottom) from the API
http://1drv.ms/1KBkitP

Comment: It's a JSON format. Where do you see multi-part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved my problem. The code give below

```
public async static Task<string> UploadFiles(StorageFile[] files)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("ru"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", "token=" + SessionToken);
            var content = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    var streamData = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                    var bytes = new byte[streamData.Size];
                    using (var dataReader = new DataReader(streamData))
                    {
                        await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)streamData.Size);
                        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
                    }
                    string fileToUpload = file.Path;
                    using (var fstream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
                    {
                        var streamContent = new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(bytes);
                        streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                        {
                            Name = "files[]",
                            FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload),

                        };
                        content.Add(streamContent);
                    }
                }
            }
            var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(UploadFilesURI, UriKind.Absolute), content);
            var contentResponce = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<API.ResponceUploadFiles.RootObject>(contentResponce);
            return result.cache;
        }
        catch { return ""; }

    }
```